# Binance API Error(code=-2010) Account has insufficient balance for requested action

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I check balance of my account with this code.

```
balance = client.get_account()
free = [b['free'] for b in balance['balances'] if b['asset'] == 'BTC']
locked = [b['locked'] for b in balance['balances'] if b['asset'] == 'BTC']

# check balance for this coin
all_balance = float(free[0]) + float(locked[0])
print(all_balance)
```

It show output is

```
0.00102323
```

After that, I try to sell with this code.

```
prices = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=coin_name)

# Buy 10 Dollar for this price
s = 10 / df['Sell_Signal_Price'].iloc[0]

# round to 1 decimal
sell_quantity = round(s, 5)
print(sell_quantity)   #It show output is 0.00022

order = client.order_limit_sell(
    symbol= coin_name,
    quantity=sell_quantity,
    price=float(prices['price']))
```

It show error like this.

```
APIError(code=-2010): Account has insufficient balance for requested action.
```

My account balance is 0.00102323 which more than 0.00022 why it show this error? How to fix it?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you need `buy` instead of `sell` - `order_limit_buy()`

Answer (score 0):

Happens when you don't have BNB as the asset to pay fee , therefore binance fee will be deducted from your coin , therefore reducing your quantity. Two ways to fizlx:

1. Have some BNB to be used for fee
2. Reduce the quantity you are trying to sell ...try something like 0.9 of your quantity

Answer (score 0):

This could be that you have exceeded the amount of orders. Just delete your orders and try to minimize your order sells.